# Multiple Apps in play , something similar to multiple apps in django

Tags: django, scala

In Django we can develop multiple apps(own models, view etc) grouped logically with same database  and common setting files but different uri. Is there something similar in play.

e.g in django we can have two apps `books` and `author` with apis like `abc.com/v1/book/1`,  `abc/com/v1/author/peter`

Comment: I guess... https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/sbtSubProjects

Comment: Can we use common settings file for all the sub projects. I did saw that documentation but it wasn't clear enough to me.

Comment: This section doesn't help? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/sbtSubProjects#Sharing-common-variables-and-code

Comment: It helped but I was looking for something like having only one build.sdt file for main project. What i understood from the doc is that if let's say we have Dev and prod environment the. I will have to keep dev and prod settings file on both the location . Main project as well as sub project.

Comment: You can absolutely have one build.sbt file. In fact, in my experience it makes things a hell of a lot easier